# I was installing the Tomcat in my eclipse but while adding the server I am getting the error

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inoR8.png)I was installing the Tomcat in my eclipse but while adding the server I am getting the error

I have tried to install it again and again but it was not working
also Reinstalled the eclipse, I Also tried its different versions.

Comment: You might try letting Eclipse download and unpack a clean copy for you. *Installed* ones might be different in unknown ways, for example, is there a `tomcat-users.xml` file in that conf folder?